# Is there know algorithm for the vehicle route coverage?

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial

I have the vehicle route as input: Lon1,Lat1; Lon2,Lat2; Lon3,Lat3; etc and I have the vehicle movement coordinates during the day.

And I need to find out what part of the route the vehicle had covered. Are there some ready algorithms for that before I start implementing my own?

Here is the illustration for the task:

[image]

Comment: Interesting question! However, as an experienced user here, you probably know that this question is not a particularly good fit for SO. This site is not about "this is my problem, please solve it for me completely", but rather "I tried A, the result was B, but I expected C". Please edit the question, showing the code you tried and explain your problems with it, thus significantly increasing the probabbility to get a meaningful answer. Ideally, provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) others can inspect and help improve together with you.

Comment: How often are vehicle coordinates logged? How much distance from the route counts as 'on-route'? How accurate are measurements?

Comment: Are the routes as the birds fly or are they actual navigation data?

Comment: @Dave vehicle coordinates logged during the movement, ~ every 5 seconds during the movement. I think we can add some radius, like 10 meters around the route points polygon would be "on-route". I would say measurements accurate to ~1m.

Comment: @Surt it's actual navigation data, not birds fly.

Comment: Given your illustrations it appears to be simply the difference between longitudes. It doesn't appear that latitude matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any explicit algorithm to apply directly to this problem. If I had to program it myself:

It is clear that the problem consists of calculating the intersection of the expected route and the union of the actual vehicle trajectory segments (I introduce the union to remove possible repeated segments). This can be done by:

1. First calculate the union of the vehicle trajectory and then substract it from the expected route
2. Just substract each vehicle trajectory segment from the remaining expected route every time a new vehicle location arrives and count the substracted distance.

I think I would go for the second option, which seems more efficient at first glance. Provided that, the challenge is mostly reduced to compute the difference between the current remaining route and each arriving trajectory segment. The calculation method of this difference will vary depending on the sampling time,  desired precision, etc.

A very naive code to illustrate the idea (in C#)

```cs
       class RouteChecker
        {
            List<RouteSegment> MissingRoute = null;
            double TotalCoveredDistance = 0.0;
            Point LastVehiclePoint = default(Point);


            public RouteChecker(List<Point> expectedRoute)
            {
                MissingRoute = new List<RouteSegment>(expectedRoute.Count - 1);
                Point previousPoint = expectedRoute[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < expectedRoute.Count; i++)
                {
                    MissingRoute.Add(new RouteSegment(previousPoint, expectedRoute[i]));
                    previousPoint = expectedRoute[i];
                }
            }

            public void SetStartPoint(Point startPoint)
            {
                TotalCoveredDistance = 0.0;
                LastVehiclePoint = startPoint;
            }


            public double CheckRouteCovered(Point realRouteNextPoint)
            {

                RouteSegment vehSegment = new RouteSegment(LastVehiclePoint, realRouteNextPoint);
                LastVehiclePoint = realRouteNextPoint;

                for (int i = 0; i < MissingRoute.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!MissingRoute[i].isActive)
                        continue;

                    RouteSegment[] remainingSegments;
                    double removedDistance;
                    bool otherSegmentisFullyContained;
                    if (MissingRoute[i].Difference(vehSegment, out remainingSegments, out removedDistance, out otherSegmentisFullyContained))
                    {
                        if (remainingSegments != null)
                        {
                            MissingRoute[i] = remainingSegments[0];
                            if (remainingSegments.Length > 1)
                                MissingRoute.Add(remainingSegments[1]);
                        }
                        else
                            MissingRoute[i].isActive = false;
                       
                        TotalCoveredDistance += removedDistance;
                        if(otherSegmentisFullyContained)
                            break;
                    }                   
                }

                return TotalCoveredDistance;

            }  
   }
```

So the corresponding object would be created as

```cs
    List<Point> expectedRoute = new List<Point>() {  new Point(Lon1, Lat1),
                                                    new Point(Lon2, Lat2),
                                                    new Point(Lon3, Lat3),
                                                    new Point(Lon4, Lat4),
                                                    new Point(Lon5, Lat5)
                                                    //[...]
                                                  };

     RouteChecker myChecker = new RouteChecker(expectedRoute);

     myChecker.SetStartPoint(new Point(vehicleStartLon, vehicleStartLat));
```

and then, each 5 seconds

```cs
   double CoveredDistance = myChecker.CheckRouteCovered(new Point(vehicleNextLon, vehicleNextLat));
```

The RouteSegment class is just a class to manage all the geometric operations with points and segments.

```cs
 private class RouteSegment
{
    const double ParallelMinAngleRadians = Math.PI / 180;
    const double MaxOnRouteDist = 10;

    Point P1, P2;
    public bool isActive = true;
    public RouteSegment(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        P1 = p1;
        P2 = p2;
    }             

    public bool Difference(RouteSegment otherSegment, out RouteSegment[] RemainingRouteSegments, out double removedDistance,out bool otherSegmentisFullyContained)
    {
        otherSegmentisFullyContained = false;

        if(!IsParallelTo(otherSegment))
        {
            removedDistance = 0.0;
            RemainingRouteSegments = null;
            return false;
        }

        if (Contains(otherSegment.P1))
        {
            if (Contains(otherSegment.P2))
            {
                removedDistance = Distance(otherSegment.P1, otherSegment.P2);
                if (Distance(otherSegment.P2, P1) < Distance(otherSegment.P2, P2))
                    RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(P1, otherSegment.P2), new RouteSegment(otherSegment.P1, P2) };
                else
                    RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(P1, otherSegment.P1), new RouteSegment(otherSegment.P2, P2) };

                otherSegmentisFullyContained = true;

                return true;                        
            }
            else
            {
                if(Distance(otherSegment.P2,P1)< Distance(otherSegment.P2, P2))
                {
                    RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(otherSegment.P1, P2) };
                    removedDistance = Distance(otherSegment.P1, P1);
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(P1,otherSegment.P1) };
                    removedDistance = Distance(otherSegment.P1, P2);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (Contains(otherSegment.P2))
        {
            if (Distance(otherSegment.P1, P1) < Distance(otherSegment.P1, P2))
            {
                RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(otherSegment.P2, P2) };
                removedDistance = Distance(otherSegment.P2, P1);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                RemainingRouteSegments = new RouteSegment[] { new RouteSegment(P1, otherSegment.P2) };
                removedDistance = Distance(otherSegment.P2, P2);
                return true;
            }
        }
        else if (otherSegment.Contains(P1))
        {
            RemainingRouteSegments = null;
            removedDistance = Distance(P1, P2);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            removedDistance = 0.0;
            RemainingRouteSegments = null;
            return false;
        }
                       
    }

    bool Contains(Point p)
    {
        double A = P1.Y - P2.Y;
        double B = P2.X - P1.X;
        double dist = Math.Abs(A * (p.X - P1.X) + B * (p.Y - P1.Y)) / Distance(P1, P2);
        return dist < MaxOnRouteDist;
    }

               
    bool IsParallelTo(RouteSegment otherSegment)
    {
        double v1X = P2.X - P1.X;
        double v1Y = P2.Y - P1.Y;
        double v2X = otherSegment.P2.X - otherSegment.P1.X;
        double v2Y = otherSegment.P2.Y - otherSegment.P1.Y;
        return Math.Abs(v1X * v2X + v1Y * v2Y) / Distance(P1, P2) / Distance(otherSegment.P1, otherSegment.P2) < Math.Cos(ParallelMinAngleRadians);
    }

    static double  Distance(Point p, Point q)
    {
        double dX = p.X - q.X;
        double dY = p.Y - q.Y;
        return Math.Sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
    }
}
```

Sorry for this much code. I found it easier to program it than to explain all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of:

- Cumulative distance on-route (initialized to zero)
- Max prior position along route
- Prior position
- Prior position status (on/off route)

Every 5 second when we get a new position:

If:

- the new position is on the route
- the new position is further along the route than the max prior position
- the immediately prior position is on the route

Then add |(new position) - (prior position)| to cumulative distance along route.

Finally, return (cumulative distance along route) / (length of route).

The reason we bother with the max position along route is to avoid double-counting some length of route if the drive backtracks for some reason.

I'm only counting segments of route where the current & prior position are both on the route. You could be more forgiving here and base the decision on just the current position. It shouldn't make much difference in the problem as described.